# ktor client https request with self-signed certificate

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have a Ktor server application (rest api) running with a self signed certificate.

It works fine from a browser (after a warning and a confirmation) port 80 is redirected to 8443.

But if I try this from a Ktor Apache Client:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {

    val client = HttpClient(Apache) {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            serializer = GsonSerializer()
        }
    }

    val job = GlobalScope.launch {
        try {
            //self-signed certificate
            val resultWillFail = client.get<String>("https://10.0.0.11:8443/get-my-services")
            println("${resultWillFail}")
            val resultOk = client.get<String>("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page") //ok
            println("${resultOk}")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Error: ${e.message}")
        }
    }

    job.join()
}
```

My request to https://10.0.0.11:8443/get-my-services will fail:

> **Error: General SSLEngine problem**

I also tried the same using curl:

> **curl: (77) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - The certificate chain was issued
>   by an authority that is not trusted.**

So my question would be: How to use a self signed certificate with ktor client (Apache) ?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to configure Apache HttpClient to ignore self signed certificates, and pass that to KTor. Based on the information [here](https://memorynotfound.com/ignore-certificate-errors-apache-httpclient/), you can ignore self signed certificate validation with the following code:

```
// use the TrustSelfSignedStrategy to allow Self Signed Certificates
val sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
        .create()
        .loadTrustMaterial(TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
        .build()

val allowAllHosts = NoopHostnameVerifier()
val connectionFactory = SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, allowAllHosts)

val client = HttpClients
        .custom()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(connectionFactory)
        .build()
```

The last thing you have to do is to use the client in your KTor code. I haven't tried that myself yet, but let me see know how you go.

Comment: Erik, your solution works!!! I modified it to work with ktor. I will add the updated code in a few minutes. Thank you !

Comment: Note that this solution is insecure and should not be used in production as it defeats the purpose of using TLS in the first place. A valid certificate should be used instead.

Answer (score 13):

**Based on Erik answer this is how I made Ktor Apache Client to accept a self-signed certificate:**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    val client = HttpClient(Apache) {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            serializer = GsonSerializer()
        }
        engine {
            customizeClient {
                setSSLContext(
                    SSLContextBuilder
                        .create()
                        .loadTrustMaterial(TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
                        .build()
                )
                setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier())
            }
        }
    }

    val job = GlobalScope.launch {
        try {
            val sslGetResult = client.get<String>("https://10.0.0.11:8443/get-my-services")
            println("${sslGetResult}")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Error: ${e.message}")
        }
    }

    job.join()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution, I'm sure it will come handy in the future!

Comment: Is there something short like this for `HttpClient(Java)` ?